# jquery find index() of same node name

Tags: jquery, indexing, traversal, nodename

I have this setup, just to find the index() of an element, but it should look at elements of the same level with the same nodename.

The returning numbers are not as expected. See the code comment. I want filteredByNodeNameIndex to be '2'.

Hope this example code is clear enough:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>TestDrive</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        function TestDrive()
        {
            var $obj = $("#div2");
            console.log("$obj.length:" + $obj.length); // returns: 1

            var $filtered = $obj.parent().children($obj[0].nodeName); // find all divs in same parent
            console.log("$filtered.length:" + $filtered.length); // returns: 3 

            var $obj_clone = $filtered.find($obj); // find original element again. Is something wrong here? 
            console.log("$objAgain.length:" + $obj_clone.length); // returns: 0

            var filteredByNodeNameIndex = $obj_clone.index(); // i want the number 2 here
            console.log("filteredByNodeNameIndex:" + filteredByNodeNameIndex); // returns: -1
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="new TestDrive()">
    <div id="container"> 
        <!-- some random elements just for test -->
        <a></a>
        <div id='div1'></div>
        <div id='div2'></div>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <a></a>
        <div></div>
        <a></a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Who can spot where this is wrong?

Comment: What is not working?  Are the numbers coming out wrong, is the code blowing up?

Comment: The numbers are not as expected. See the code comment. I want filteredByNodeNameIndex to be '2'.

var filteredByNodeNameIndex = $obj_clone.index(); // i want the number 2 here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of `.find`:

```
var $obj_clone = $filtered.filter($obj);
```

The problem with `.find` is that it looks for children of the matched element, not siblings. From the docs:

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched
>   elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Compared to `.filter`:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or
>   pass the function's test.

Answer (score 2):

[find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) only searches children of the selected node.  You are trying to use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)'s functionality.  You need the following:

```
        var $obj_clone = $filtered.filter($obj); // find original element again. Is something wrong here?
```

Answer (score 1):

At the third attempt, you're trying to find the the child in itself, which obviously doesn't return the desired value.

Illustrated:

```
 var $filtered = $obj.parent().children($obj[0].nodeName);
 //Select set A

 var $obj_clone = $filtered.find($obj);
 //Search for set A among the CHILDREN of set A --> Fails, obviously?

 var filteredByNodeNameIndex = $obj_clone.index();
 //Unexpected results.
```

Comment: This is true, but doesn't explain how to fix it.  See the other responses about `filter`.

Comment: The question was not "How to fix it", but "Explain what's wrong".

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var $obj_clone = $filtered.filter($obj);
```

.find() only looks for children